# Missing $ inserted in multiple lines

Tags: math-mode, errors

I m new for latex, When I try to create my document, I have following part. But its not functioning and giving

> $ missing

error.

```
\textbf{Algorithm 1}\\
\textit{ld  \Leftarrow (ld_1,ld_2,ld_3,...,ld_N)} \\
\textit{D \Leftarrow ld_1 + ld_2 + ld_3+...+ld_N } \\
\textit{P$_a$ \Leftarrow available power} \\
\textbf{for }  i $ = 1 $ to  N \textbf{ do}\\
    \textit{la$_*i$ \Leftarrow P$_a$ \div D \times ld$_i$}\\
\textit{\textbf{end for}}\\
la$_*$ represents the allocated power to each load and its calculated using\\
\textit{la$_*$ = la$_*1$,la$_*2$,la$_*3$...,la$_*N$}\\
\textit{la$_*1$+la$_*2$+la$_*3$+ ...+la$_*N$}
```

What am I missing here??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using math commands like `\Leftarrow` and `_` in text mode. I think the whole thing should be a math environment like `align` and the text in it should be `\text`. See the manual of the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package for more information.

Comment: Since you are new to LaTeX i suggest to read an introduction to get a grip how LaTeX works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It lacks `$`. `\leftarrow` must be surrounded by `$`, as well as `_`. You should use packages like [`algorithmicx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) to present your algorithms. `\\` should not be used to change line. This works but is far from legible :

```
\textbf{Algorithm 1}\\
\textit{ld  $\Leftarrow (ld_1,ld_2,ld_3,...,ld_N)$} \\
\textit{D$ \Leftarrow ld_1 + ld_2 + ld_3+...+ld_N$} \\
\textit{P$_a$ $\Leftarrow$ available power} \\
\textbf{for }  $i  = 1$  to  N  \textbf{ do}\\
    \textit{la$_*i$ $\Leftarrow P_a \div D \times ld_i$}\\
\textit{\textbf{end for}}\\
la$_*$ represents the allocated power to each load and its calculated using\\
\textit{la$_*$ = la$_*1$,la$_*2$,la$_*3$...,la$_*N$}\\
\textit{la$_*1$+la$_*2$+la$_*3$+ ...+la$_*N$}
```